# How to get the match[0] with sed

Tags: sed

I have this string :  "This is the First - This is the seconde  - this is the big"

I try to get only the text before the first -  like This is the First

```
echo "This is the First - This is the seconde  - this is the big"  | sed -re 's/\-/\l/g'
```

but the code remove only the -

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete everything after matching `-`:

```sh
$ s='This is the First - This is the seconde  - this is the big'
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/-.*//'
This is the First
```

Use `s/ *-.*//` if you want to remove the spaces before `-` as well.

If removing spaces before `-` isn't a concern, you can use `cut` as well. This solution is also easier to extend:

```sh
$ echo "$s" | cut -d- -f1
This is the First 

$ echo "$s" | cut -d- -f1-2
This is the First - This is the seconde
```

This will use `-` to split the input into fields and then display only the required fields.

Comment: Great thanks for help.  I don't have reputation enough to vote.  Thank you very much.   last question.  if I want to display:  This is the First - This is the seconde   what can do with sed or cut? Thanks

Comment: @timimi I've edited the answer, it can be done with `sed` too, but that is more complicated

Comment: @timimi [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged, please simply accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new followup question if you have one.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks